# Combining small caps and sans serif?

Tags: small-caps, sans-serif

Is it possible to combine small caps (`\textsc`) and sans serif (`\textsf`)? I am using the default LaTeX fonts.

Comment: The Computer Sans typeface has no small caps font.

Comment: @egreg Is there another (similar) font which does have small caps?

Answer (score 6):

You can nest `\textsf` and `\textsc` in either order, but unless there is a font of that form, LaTeX will issue a warning and substitute a different style.

One that does work with no warnings is the `newtxtext` font set.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\begin{document}

sc-sf \textsc{\textsf{One two Three}}


sf-sc \textsf{\textsc{One two Three}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you’re using `fontspec`, many sans-serif fonts have small caps, including TeX Gyre Heros and Adventor. You can also give the `\setsansfont` command the `SmallCapsFont =` option.

Comment: @Davislor well that's true but I guess the OP isn't, but it wouldn't hurt if you posted a fontspec based answer as a comparison.

Answer (score 2):

For the case the font does not support small caps, I recently wrote a small script that transforms lowercase letters into smaller uppercase versions. It even works with ä, ö, ü and ß.

`\c{textsmaller}[2]` can be replaced by `\c{textscale}\cB\{0.7\cE\}` to make customisability more granular.

When one's specific case is not covered, these steps might help:

- include a special exception in the regex command
- replace `[^A-Z]` with `[a-z]`
- replace `\0` with `\1`

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xparse,relsize}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\textsmallcaps}{ m }{% Define new command with one mandatory argument
    \textapperance_smallcaps:n { #1 }% Call
}%

\tl_new:N \l__textapperance_textsmallcaps_input_tl% Initialize string variable
\cs_new_protected:Npn \textapperance_smallcaps:n #1 
{% Create hidden command with one argument
    \tl_set:Nx \l__textapperance_textsmallcaps_input_tl { #1 } % Fully expand contents and store them in the variable
    \regex_replace_all:nnN 
    { ([^A-Z]+) } 
    { \c{textsmaller}[2]\cB\{\c{uppercase}\cB\{\0\cE\}\cE\} } 
    \l__textapperance_textsmallcaps_input_tl % Replace everything thats NOT a capital letter by \textsmaller[2]{\uppercase{<match>}}
    \tl_use:N \l__textapperance_textsmallcaps_input_tl   % Return
}
 
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: ä, ö, ü have to be lowercase! The reason is, that l3regex does not support utf8 for pdfLaTeX, yet.